# Very low rate of obstacles_detection rtabmap

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the standalone nodelet obstacles_detection to get the obstacles from my stereo camera. When I run it, I get a slow rate of < 1 Hz and for the real-time obstacle detection that is not suitable. How can I speed up the process? Here is how I launched that nodelet:

```
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="obstacles_detection" args="load rtabmap_ros/obstacles_detection stereo_nodelet"-->
   <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="obstacles_detection" args="standalone rtabmap_ros/obstacles_detection">
      <remap from="cloud" to="/zed/zed_node/point_cloud/cloud_registered"/>
      <remap from="obstacles" to="/planner_cloud"/>

      <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="base_footprint"/>
      <param name="map_frame_id" type="string" value="map"/>
      <param name="min_cluster_size" type="int" value="20"/>
      <param name="max_obstacles_height" type="double" value="0.0"/>
   </node>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326890/very-low-rate-of-obstacles_detection-rtabmap/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-06-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-06-25**:
I have turned on the "disparity2cloud" nodelet and supplied the disparity images with the regular camera_info but for some reason the cloudXYZ from that nodelet comes in a strange format (data is symmetrical) and the /planner_cloud data is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest to downsample the point clouds before feeding it to `obstacles_detection`. See `pcl_ros`'s VoxelGrid filter for example: http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros/Tutorials/VoxelGrid%20filtering, try with a leaf size of 5 cm.

Another way is to use [rtabmap_ros/point_cloud_xyz](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/#rtabmap_ros.2BAC8-point_cloud_xyz) nodelet to convert depth image to point cloud using decimation for fast downsampling.

```
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="points_xyz" args="standalone rtabmap_ros/point_cloud_xyz">
   <remap from="depth/image"         to="/zed/zed_node/depth/image"/>
   <remap from="depth/camera_info"   to="/zed/zed_node/depth/camera_info"/>
   <remap from="cloud"               to="voxel_cloud" />
   <param name="decimation"  type="double" value="4"/>
   <param name="voxel_size"  type="double" value="0.05"/>
   <param name="approx_sync" type="bool" value="false"/>
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-06-25**:
@matlabbe cheers, I will try it

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-07-09**:
@matlabbe yes it works but the question is, can I use the depth cloud produced by the rtabmap instead of my own cloud? I have used /rtabmap/cloud_map and I can see that obstacles_detection node subscribes to that but gives no data to /planner_cloud topic even though /rtabmap/cloud_map is not empty

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-07-09**:
I don't recommend passing `/rtabmap/cloud_map` to `obstacles_detection`, as you could use directly `/rtabmap/cloud_obstacles`. However, if you feed those obstacles to `obstacle_layer` from costmap_2d, you should use the voxel cloud of the answer above as input to `obstacles_detection`, then feed the resulting obstacles to `obstacle_layer`.

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-07-09**:
@matlabbe sorry, I did not follow your suggestion. Do you mean it is better to use `/rtabmap/cloud_obstacles` inside the `obstacle_layer` and use the output of the `obstacle_layer` (which is `/planner_cloud`) to the local_costmap_param?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-07-09**:
`zed_node` -> (depth image) -> `point_cloud_xyz` -> (voxel cloud) -> `obstacles_detection` -> (obstacles cloud, which you call /planner_cloud) -> `obstacle_layer`

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-07-10**:
@matlabbe Yes I get that, this was my initial setup, I am just trying to avoid using the depth image

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-07-10**:
Not sure why you would want to avoid the depth image. Inputs to local costmap should be the sensor (or obstacles derived directly from sensor) directly, not the map from rtabmap.

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-07-11**:
@matlabbe I think you misunderstood. I do not want to avoid the depth image, I just want to avoid the depth image produced by ZED and use the depth image (or PCL) produced by RTABmap algorithm.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-07-11**:
rtabmap doesn't produce depth image. If you mean the point cloud, obstacles_detection nodelet does exactly the same than rtabmap for a single frame (you can pass the same `Grid/` parameters), which is a format more suitable for local costmap than the full map (`cloud_map` or `cloud_obstacles` or `cloud_ground`) of rtabmap. Using the full map as input to local costmap is inefficient and not safe (in particular in localization mode).